# Динамическое добавление объектов в ItemsControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Код xaml

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="list1">
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>...........
```

И условный код c#

```
     List<string> films = new List<string>();
        private async void MainFilm()
        {
            films.Add("Tyrannosaurus");
            films.Add("Amargasaurus");
            films.Add("Mamenchisaurus");
            films.Add("Deinonychus");
            films.Add("Compsognathus");
            list1.ItemsSource = films;
            list1.ItemsSource = await Task.Run(() => dino());

        }

        public List<string> dino()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            films.Add("Deinonychus");
            films.Add("Compsognathus");
            return films;
        }
```

Собственно после загрузки окна, появляются только первые 5 компонентов, как же сделать так, чтоб, через 5 секунд после запуска добавились динамически еще два?

В общем, как динамически обновлять компоненты в ItemsControl? Заранее благодарю ")

Comment: 1) использовать привязки 2) использовать ObservableCollection 3) Использовать асинхронное ожидание `TaskDelay(...)`

Comment: Благодарю, в принципе разобрался, с ObservableCollection, все получилось. А то не знал куда копать ")

Comment: @tym32167 Остался один маленький вопрос, собственно как добавлять асинхронно ObservableCollection и обновлять DataContext, а то форма подвисает во время добавления элементов.

Comment: `await Task.Delay(5000); myList.Add(...);`